# Баг столбцов Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Читаю excel-файл, задача - распарсить строку одного из столбцов на значения, проставить по строкам в новый фрейм признак каждого значения (присутствует или нет).

Две проблемы:

1. Если открываю через excel, то вижу что у строки есть тег 'Aerial Threat':
   [image: У Роналду есть тег "воздушная угроза"]

Но в фрейме после загрузки у него нет этого значения в столбце, да и вообще есть не те, что показывает excel:
[image: Notebook]

2. Корявенько, но привёл все теги к матрице one-hot-encoding. В ней нашёлся мало что условно-дублирующий тег (с этим я ещё разберусь), так в списке колонок он есть, а доступ к нему через скобочную нотацию я получить не могу (криво код прикрепляется, далее скрин, файл блокнота прикрепил):

[image: Код]
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Хз как прикреплять файлы, вот ссылка на гуглдок)):https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15kq5kzHAP1CHhxmv4gWkppS-Os5PyT3w?usp=sharing

Comment: Проблема "решилась" когда вместо xlsx загрузил из csv

Comment: Исправил код парсинга, проблема с доступом по скобочной нотации ушла

Comment: Но вообще всё-равно непонятно, что же это было.